# VB.NET object initialization not working?

Tags: vb.net, networking, tcplistener

OK, this probably is going to be a head-banger, but why is this code not working?

```
Dim tcplistener As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener
```

This does not compile with the error "`Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.`"
The thing is, I have to declare it as `New` because otherwise I will get a null-reference exception...
Does anybody know what I am doing wrong, or should do differently?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [constructor overloads available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.tcplistener.aspx). They all have parameters - so you can't just create a `TcpListener` without any arguments. What port do you want to listen to, for example?

You might want something like:

```
Dim tcplistener As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(8080)
```

which should work fine.

This isn't specific to `TcpListener` - you should always consider which arguments you want to pass to a constructor.